# How to prevent context react re-rendering

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-context

I made a simple react application with context as the state management, however, the default behavior of this context is always **re-rendering every state** even though the changes made only for one state. How can I prevent this behavior like in Redux, where the component will re-render if the state being used is changed?

I made this simple app in Codesandbox, you can try it at https://wu0qz.csb.app/

Thanks

Comment: Split the context into multiple contexts ContextA and ContextB? If you attempt this approach you will probably need to use a `useMemo` in your provider component so that the context value holding both the state value and setState isn't recreated for the context that did not change.

Comment: This is how react works. If a component (i.e. `Controller`) rerenders, then all of that component's sub-tree is also rerendered. `Controller` rerenders when its state is updated by `Comp2`.

Comment: Let say i have ten states to be controlled. Should I split them into different 10 files of context? or is there another way to keep the states clean in one context without triggering the others?

Comment: In that case you probably want to go with a state container (redux) or implement something similar by wrapping each ui component and pass only the variables they need from the context

Comment: so context actually just used for passing the props? not for storing the states?